# How to let strtol() function in C to interpret the string as two's complement number?

Tags: c, strtol

I want to convert a given string to a int number. However, I realized that, strtol() would interprert things like "0xffc" as having value 4092, instead of interpreting it as a 2's complement number, which should be -4. I cannot modify the string as it is given as command line argument. So how can I get a int number that is the result of interpreting the given string as a 2's complement number?

Comment: I think OP made a mistake, 0xffc is not -4 in char, short or int. Why it's 1 and a half bytes?

Comment: @RishikeshRaje in 16 bit 2s complement, that is still 4092. Only 0xfffc would be negative. I think OP is referring to a special width value.

Comment: Yilei Huang. Please specify the value range you want to achieve and at which positive value the reinterpretation to negative is wanted.

Comment: Why on earth would 0xffc be a negative value? There are no 12 bit CPUs.

Comment: If you know your system will handle it properly, you can assign the converted value to a 12 bit signed bit-field. `struct { int x : 12; } x = { value };`

Answer (score 1):

The value 0xffc will become -4 when viewed as a 12 bit integer (2s complement). Otherwise (int, short, ...) it is just 4092.

Consider

```
int v= strtol(v) ;
if ( v & 1<<11 ) v |= ~0xfff ;
```

Or for any N bit:

```
const int N = 12 ;
int v= strtol(v) ;
if ( v & 1<<(N-1) ) v |= ~ ((1<<N)-1) ;
```

Comment: Why use implementation specific bit manipulation instead of a straight forward conditional subtraction? (That is, the effect will be depending on the width of the type representation. Not so for just subtracting an appropriate value.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are expecting 12bit 2s complement values.
In this, the treshold, i.e. the highest positive value is 2047 (0x8ff).
To achieve a value range of -2048 ... 2047 (the range for usual "quasi symmetric" 12bit representation), simply do this on the variable which received the value.

```
if(iValue>2047) /* note that in the wide range of the receiving variable, this makes sense */
{
    iValue-=4096; /* in the 16bit (or more) representation, this makes sense */
}
```

This code does of course assume that the read values are within 0....4095 and that the receiving variable is wider than 12 bits, but so seem you to do.
It might seem tempting to do 16bit bit operations, but they would require making assumptions on the bit width of the containing variable. Just subtracting the appropriate value ONLY makes an assumption on the represented smaller value range, not on the internal representation in the variable.